# PeopleSoft Query - Union with Prompt (prompt used in both queries in union)

Tags: peoplesoft

I have a query built using Query Manager that contains a union. I have a prompt for PAY_END_DT that I would like to use in both queries in the union.
When I click the View SQL tab, I can see that each of the queries references the prompt.

```
 AND A.PAY_END_DT = :1 

 AND C.PAY_END_DT = :1
```

When I copy the query into SQL Studio and replace the prompt with a date, I get the results I expect.  However, when I run the query in PeopleSoft, it errors out.
Checking the log, I see that the prompt in the second query has been changed to :2 (I do not have a second prompt). I have tried changing the criteria in the second
query to an expression, and entering :1, but this too, gets changed to :2.  Does anyone have any ideas how to use the one prompt in both queries?

PeopleSoft 8.9
Tools 8.50
SQL Server 2012

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem in 8.53 but what you could consider as a workaround is to place your query without the PAY_END_DT prompt clauses into a view in Application Designer, build this view, add it to the query security and then use it in Query Manager with one prompt for PAY_END_DT.

Answer (score 0):

**try changing from:**

```
AND A.PAY_END_DT = :1 
and AND C.PAY_END_DT = :1
```

**to:**

```
AND A.PAY_END_DT = :1 
and AND C.PAY_END_DT = A.PAY_END_DT
```

Comment: Thank you - but unfortunately, because it's part of the union, the second query doesn't recognize A.PAY_END_DT. I get: The multi-part identifier "A.PAY_END_DT" could not be bound.